# Is there a better way to assign a new value to a numpy array scalar?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scalar, copy-assignment

I am doing some quick calculations on a scalar value from a numpy array.  As it says in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html#array-scalars),

> The primary advantage of using array scalars is that they preserve the
>   array type (Python may not have a matching scalar type available, e.g.
>   int16)...

But is there a better (faster, and more concise) way of assigning a new value to an existing array scalar than this:

```
>>> x = np.array(2.0, dtype='float32')
```

which works but is not that convenient (I am doing other arithmetic and want to preserve the type throughout).

This doesn't work for obvious reasons:

```
>>> x = np.array(1.0, dtype='float32')
>>> print(x, type(x))
1.0 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> x = 2.0
>>> print(x, type(x))
2.0 <class 'float'>
```

Neither does this:

```
>>> x = np.array(1.0, dtype='float32')
>>> x[] = 2.0
  File "<ipython-input-319-7f36071ff81d>", line 2
    x[] = 2.0
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Nor this:

```
>>> x = np.array(1.0, dtype='float32')
>>> x[:] = 2.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-62cd4ca238ce> in <module>()
      1 x = np.array(1.0, dtype='float32')
----> 2 x[:] = 2.0

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

UPDATE:

Based on comments below (thanks) I have now realised that I am not actually using array scalars.  `x` is a zero-dimensional array.

Here is how to create an array scalar:

```
>>> a = np.array((1.0, 2.0, 3.0), dtype='float32')
>>> x = a[0]
>>> print(x, type(x))
1.0 <class 'numpy.float32'>
```

Or simply:

```
>>> x = np.float32(1.0)
>>> print(x, type(x))
1.0 <class 'numpy.float32'>
```

Comment: Also, even if they were mutable—`x = 2.0` just rebinds the name `x` to point at a different object. The only thing it's mutating is the global namespace. (If you're coming to Python from another language—especially C++—this is probably your confusion. `x` is not a variable in the C++ sense of a memory location with a type and value, it's just a name in a namespace bound to an object, and the object has a memory location, type, and value.)

Comment: @abarnert NumPy scalars (such as `x`) is just arrays of shape `()`. They *are* mutable, as demonstrated in the answer by hpaulj.

Comment: Thanks @abarnet.  I will correct the code in the question to change `x = np.array((2.0), dtype='float32')` to `x = np.array(2.0, dtype='float32')`.  The question is still valid I think.

Comment: @jmd_dk: `x` is not an array scalar. `numpy.float32(1.0)` would be an array scalar. `x` is a 0-dimensional array.

Comment: Okay I get it now.  I need to either re-phrase the whole question.  "Is there a way to assign a new value to a zero-dimensional numpy array?" or delete it.  The answer is good thought so I'm inclined to leave it.  What do people think?

Comment: @Bill If you rephrase the question, show _both_ `np.float32(1.0)` and also `np.array(1.0, dtype=np.float32)`, and show how you tried all the different things (also try `x[:] = 2.0`, which will give you an informative error), and then the answer will fit your question even better than it already does.

Comment: @user2357112 Ah, you are right! This distinction was not clear to me from the other comments, as something like `numpy.float32(1.0)` was never mentioned here, nor in the question.

Comment: @jmd_dk Yes, user was presumably assuming (as I was) that anyone trying to answer the question would know the difference between a scalar and an array—but it's pretty obvious that the OP didn't, and that was the primary source of confusion behind the question. So I should have made things clearer from the start.

Comment: Maybe someone should post another answer showing how to assign a new value to an array scalar?  I.e. `x = np.float32(1.0)`.  It doesn't really belong in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A 0d array can be modified, but an `array scalar` cannot:

```
In [199]: x = np.array(1.0, 'float32')
In [200]: x
Out[200]: array(1., dtype=float32)
In [201]: x.shape
Out[201]: ()
In [202]: x[...] = 2
In [203]: x
Out[203]: array(2., dtype=float32)
In [204]: x[()] =3
In [205]: x
Out[205]: array(3., dtype=float32)
```

You have to mutate `x`, not assign a new object to the variable.

That said, I don't see why one would want, or need, to do this.

---

This 0d array is not quite the same as an `array scalar`:

```
In [207]: y = np.float32(1)
In [208]: y[...] = 2
....
TypeError: 'numpy.float32' object does not support item assignment
```

Extracting an element from an array with indexing produces an `array scalar`:

```
In [210]: type(x[()])
Out[210]: numpy.float32
```

The float32 object has many of the array attributes, even methods, but it isn't quite same:

```
In [211]: x.shape
Out[211]: ()
In [212]: y.shape
Out[212]: ()
```

---

An array can be indexed with a tuple the same size as its shape.  `arr[1,2]` is the same as `arr[(1,2)]`.  The shape of `x` is `()`, so it can only be indexed with an empty tuple, `x[()]`.  Similarly `arr[:,:]` works for a 2d array, but not for 1d.  `...` means, any number of slices, so works with `x[...]`.

Enough of the `__getitem__` has been defined for `np.generic` class objects to allow indexing like `[...]` and `[()]`. But the assignment has not been defined.

It might be useful to look at the class hierarchy of classes like `np.ndarray`, `np.int_`, `np.float32`, `np.float`, and `np.int`.

### fuller quote

From your link: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html#array-scalars

> NumPy generally returns elements of arrays as array scalars (a scalar with an associated dtype). Array scalars differ from Python scalars, but for the most part they can be used interchangeably (the primary exception is for versions of Python older than v2.x, where integer array scalars cannot act as indices for lists and tuples). There are some exceptions, such as when code requires very specific attributes of a scalar or when it checks specifically whether a value is a Python scalar. Generally, problems are easily fixed by explicitly converting array scalars to Python scalars, using the corresponding Python type function (e.g., int, float, complex, str, unicode).
>
> The primary advantage of using array scalars is that they preserve the array type (Python may not have a matching scalar type available, e.g. int16). Therefore, the use of array scalars ensures identical behaviour between arrays and scalars, irrespective of whether the value is inside an array or not. NumPy scalars also have many of the same methods arrays do.

The 2nd paragraph is written the context of the 1st.  It attempts to explain why elements of an array are `returned as array scalars`.  That is, why `arr[0,1]` returns a `np.float32` object, as opposed to a Python `float`.

**It is not suggesting that we create an `array scalar` directly.**

I first wrote this answer glossing over the difference between a 0d array, and what this quote is calling `array scalars`.

Comment: Excellent thanks.  I was not aware of `[...]` mutation.  This achieves exactly what I wanted --to simulate the effects of single-precision floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @Bill For an actual scalar (like `np.float32(1)`), `x[...]` will convert it to a 0D array, but `x[...] = 2` will raise a `TypeError`. Try both of them with scalars and with 0D arrays and with 1-element 1D arrays (along with `x[:]` and `x[()]`) until you get what's going on.

Comment: I expanded a bit on the difference between a 0d array and a `np.float32` object.  @abarnert