# How do I assign to a zero-dimensional numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have an array like `x = np.array(3)` which has `x.ndim == 0`. How do I assign a new value to this array? `x[0] = 2` gives `IndexError`, as does `x[:] = 2`.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581213/is-there-a-better-way-to-assign-a-new-value-to-a-numpy-array-scalar.

Comment: `x[...]=2` and `x[()]=2` might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `x.flat` which returns an `np.flatiter` instance:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array(3)
x.flat[:] = 2
# or x.flat[0] = 2
```

or by indexing the original array with ellipsis or an empty tuple:

```py
x[...] = 2
x[()] = 2
```

Comment: There seems to be subtle differences between these approaches (flat colon index, flat zero index, ellipses index, empty tuple index, as well as `ndarray.put` from BENY's answer): Compare for the somewhat extreme example of a zero-dimensional array of type `object`, `arr = np.empty([], dtype=object)`; the following do not seem to be interchangable: a) `arr[()] = np.array([1, 2, 3])`, b) `arr[...] = np.array([1, 2, 3])`, c) `arr.flat[:] = np.array([1, 2, 3])`, d) `arr.flat[0] = np.array([1, 2, 3])`, e) `arr.put(0, np.array([1, 2, 3]))`.

Answer (score 0):

I will using `put`

```
x.put(0,2)
x
Out[91]: array(2)
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about this function. It seems to use `.flat` internally; are there cases where `.put` is better or is it just a stylistic preference? I suppose if you were using `mode="wrap"` or `mode="clip"`?

Comment: @Nathan just stylistic preference :-)